# Is there a way to make one table selector work for several tables differently in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, formatting

I am pulling data from an application that automatically loads the data into tables in HTML and CSS. I want to create a CSS file so that my company will not have to reformat the HTML and/or CSS every time they download the data tables from the app. I figured that I would alter the CSS to cater to the application-generated HTML. This way, when we download the HTML for the data tables every month, we only need to save the HTML file, and the CSS file will format it every time. I want half the tables on the right side of the page and half on the left, but right now they are all on the left.

The issue comes in here: every table is under the same class name. Usually, I would just name every table to an appropriate class name in the HTML and adjust formatting in the CSS file. Since I don't want to touch the auto-formatted HTML, though, is there a way to dynamically format a single table selector in CSS?

I was thinking that if CSS were a dynamic language, I would just make a variable, add one to it every time that the table selector is called upon, and have every odd variable on the right and every even variable on the left. I don't have much experience with JavaScript or other scripting languages, but is this method possible within CSS, or is there another way I can go about doing this?

Comment: If the order of the tables is always the same (known in advance) you can use [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out the nth child selector here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child. Assuming all of your tables are at the same level of your HTML, this should allow you to select every other!